# Django - TypeError at feeds() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to add comments to my project and I've got this error: `feeds() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`. Here is my code.

views.py

```
@login_required
def feeds(request, id):
    feeds_list = Feed.objects.all()
    feed = get_object_or_404(Feed, id=id)
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Komentarz został opublikowany.
        feed_form = FeedForm(request.POST)
        if feed_form.is_valid():
            # Utworzenie obiektu Comment, ale jeszcze nie zapisujemy go w bazie danych.
            new_feed = feed_form.save(commit=False)
            new_feed.user = request.user
            new_feed.date = timezone.now
            # Zapisanie komentarza w bazie danych.
            new_feed.save()
    else:
        feed_form = FeedForm()

    context = {'section': feeds,
               'users': users,
               'feeds_list': feeds_list,
               'feed_form': feed_form}
    return render(request, 'feed/list.html', context)
```

I think that's here is problem: `feed = get_object_or_404(Feed, id=id)`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks for help.

Edit:
urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'feedApp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.feeds, name='feeds'),
    url(r'^feed/new$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^feed/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.feed, name='post_detail'),
    # url(r'^feed/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/comment$',
    #     views.comment_feed,
    #     name='comment_feed'),
    url(r'^feed/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/delete/$',
        views.feed_delete,
        name='feed_delete'),
]
```

Comment: paste `urls.py`

Comment: The view `feeds` expects `id` to be present in urls. Your endpoint should be like this - 
localhost:8000/<id>

Comment: if there is error post full error trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your `urls` you need to add the required argument `id` to it.
edit your url to :

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.feeds, name='feeds'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not used 'id' as keyword args in `views.feeds` url.
Add `url(r'^feed/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.feeds,),`

Comment: the url in your answer is for some other function `views.feed`. And it already has `id` argument in the url.